# Date and time functions in php

Tags: php, date, time

I need to get the +7 day result, for that I did:

```
<?php 
echo "Today is ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
echo "<br/>";
echo "After 7 days: ".strtotime('+7 day');
?>
```

How to format result of +7 days in a readable form. eg: 23-05-2012 10:09:03

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this way:

```
echo "Today is ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
echo "<br/>";
echo "After 7 days: ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+7 day'));
```

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+7 day'));
```

Answer (score 2):

you want to calculate the date seven days from today.

There are a couple of ways you could go about it - the first one would be to do something like this:

echo $after7days = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);

Basically, you take the current timestamp, expressed in seconds, and add 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, which is the amount of seconds in one week.

Another way to do it, which is my preferred way and how I would do it, is this:

$after7days = strtotime("+7 days");

The outcome will be exactly the same, $after7days will have a value equal to the timestamp of the day exactly in a week from now, but it uses PHP's own strtotime() function.

Of course, if you need to output a date in a format that easy to read for humans, you can do something like this:

echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$after7days);

Answer (score 0):

Combine those two functions.

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+7 days'));
```

[`date()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) takes a second parameter where you can pass in a unix timestamp which should be used.

Answer (score 0):

To format a date in php, use the [`date`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php) function (you've already used it in your code).

Use it like this:

```
echo "After 7 days: ".date('d-m-Y H:i:s',strtotime('+7 day'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [strftime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) function to format/convert a unix timestamp to local time/date according to locale settings.